# Obtain a character entered by the user and store it into a variable (Java)

Tags: java, string, input, char, integer

The code below is to get a string entered by a user in a text box (from a GUI) and store it into a variable called aString:

```
aString = txtString.getText();
```

The code below does not work just like the code above because it is a char rather than string. What is the other way of obtaining a character from the user (as char) and storing it in a variable to be later used in the program?

```
char aChar = txtCharToString.getText();
```

Comment: `char aChar = txtCharToString.getText().charAt(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this if you need the whole characters:

```
String str = txtCharToString.getText().toString();
char[] aChar = str.toCharArray();
```

or like this if just the first char:

```
char aChar = txtCharToString.getText().charAt(0);
```

Comment: Thank you Shadi. It worked :) What if the code is lblStringtoChar.setText(aChar); and its not working because char cannot be converted to string. How would I change the code to display it in the jlabel?

Comment: you are welocome. try this : String.valueOf(aChar);